# Efficient sub-arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, big-o, sub-array

I have solved the following question but the online judge wouldn't accept it as it's not time efficient. Please help me to improve the efficiency.

Question: https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/little-shino-and-pairs/

My approach:

```
N = int(input())

lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
output = set()

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        temp_list = lst[i:j+1]
        if len(temp_list) >= 2:
            temp_list.sort()
            a = temp_list[-1]
            b = temp_list[-2]
            if a != b:
                output.add((a,b))

print(len(output))
```

Comment: What is your code trying to achieve? Sorting the list?

Comment: The problem statement is given in the link. Please look into it.